# Proxied URL basic auth redirect path

Tags: apache, proxy, basic-authentication

So, say I have a proxied url `whatever.com` that actually is proxied to show content from `whatever.mydomain.com`. `whatever.mydomain.com` then has a basic auth directory

```
<Directory /var/www/html/stuffs/internal>
      AuthType Basic
        AuthName "mumbo-jumbo"
        AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
        Require valid-user
    </Directory>
```

When the user hits `whatever.com/internal`the login form is displayed, but after logging in, they get sent to `whatever.mydomain.com/internal`for the content. How could I keep it so that after the login, the user is sent to the proxy url aswell? Or atleast make it seem so to the end user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can we solved by putting `RewriteRule` after Directory.

```
<Directory />
  AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Restricted Files"
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
</Directory>
RewriteCond %{LA-U:REQUEST_URI} !^$
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://whatever.mydomain.com/$1   [P,L]
```